# Duplicate c# listView into a listView on another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms.

Form1 contains a listView.

Form2 contains an empty listView.

I want Form2 to have all the data from the listView in Form1.

I have tried searching for this, but it appears to require a button click. Is there a way around this? How can this be implemented using C#?

```
var form1LV = listView1;
    OnButton2Click(..){
    Form2 f = new Form2(form1LV);
..
}
and in form2's constructor

Form2(object f1LV){
Form1LV = (ListView)f1LV;
}
and then assign Form1LV to listView2 in form2.

listView2 = Form1LV on button click.
```

Comment: What have you searched/tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ListView to contain the same data as another ListView, you need to copy its collection (not the control itself).

```
Form2(object f1LV)
{
    ...
    if (f1LV != null && f1LV is ListView) {
        listView2.Items.AddRange((ListView)f1LV.Items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make f1LV an object?  It can only be a ListView.

Comment: agreed. I was only copying the OP's code. The key point being you cannot simply assign listView1 to listView2